# "responsible for" in negative context

Tags: expressions

Can you use "responsible for" in a negative context?

Like the "Kids were responsible for starting the fire". As they were guilty of burning down the house.

Comment: Of course, as you just used in a perfectly good example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Indeed this dual connotation of 'responsible' and 'responsibility', where what is a positive sounding word is used to express or admit guilt, was at the centre of a major concern on the part of the government of Margaret Thatcher in Britain.

At the time of the troubles in Northern Ireland, every time there was an outrage, such as a bombing or shooting in which innocent people were killed one or other of the terrorist groups, the IRA or the Loyalist paramilitaries, would 'claim responsibility' for the incident. They did this in order to encourage their own supporters to believe that they were winning, and so that people would take them more seriously. This would be reported by the news media as 'The IRA/UVF claimed responsibility for the incident...'

However, in the view of many people, including the Government, the use of this term 'claim responsibility' appeared to give the terrorists more credibility than they merited. It seemed to portray them as 'responsible people', which was the opposite of what they really were. So in response to government and other pressure the BBC and other broadcasters stopped saying 'XYZ claimed responsibility' in favour of 'XYZ said they did it'.

Answer (score 1):

> The kids are liable in starting the fire

The general rule in using *liable* is that the party liable will be affected and exposed to consequences of the liability.

> li·a·ble  (lī′ə-bəl)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Legally obligated; responsible: liable for military service. See Synonyms at responsible.
> 2. At risk of or subject to experiencing or suffering something unpleasant. Used with to: liable to criminal charges; liable to diabetes.
> 3. Likely. Often used with reference to an unfavorable outcome: In a depression banks are liable to fail.
> 4. (Law) legally obliged or responsible; answerable
> 5. susceptible or exposed; subject
> 6. probable, likely, or capable: it's liable to happen soon.

> The kids are answerable for starting the fire.

> [an·swer·a·ble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/answerable)  (ăn′sər-ə-bəl)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Subject to being called to answer; accountable. See Synonyms at responsible.
> 2. That can be answered or refuted: an answerable charge.
> 3. Archaic
>      a. Suitable.
>      b. Corresponding.

> The kids are accountable for starting the fire.

> [ac·count·a·ble](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/accountable)  (ə-koun′tə-bəl)
>   adj.
>
> 1. Liable to being called to account; answerable. See Synonyms at responsible.
> 2. That can be explained: an accountable phenomenon.
>      ac·count′a·bil′i·ty, ac·count′a·ble·ness n.
>      ac·count′a·bly adv.

Comment: Incontestable. Except as to relevance.

Comment: But can you also use "responsible"?

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can say "the kids were responsible for starting the fire". Even though the single word "responsible" has positive connotations, the verbal phrase "to be responsible for" is neutral: it merely shows who (or what) is accountable for an activity or outcome.

- Fusion power is responsible for the light and heat that comes from the Sun.
- He is responsible for bringing the refreshments to next week's committee meeting.
- She was responsible for the success of our party in last year's elections.
- She was responsible for abusing six babies under her care.
- He was responsible for the worst killing spree in this country's history.

They're all perfectly valid.